# Can I resize the layout to width 2x more then screen width?

Tags: android, layout, view, scrollview, android-viewpager

I want to implement something like ViewPager or ScrollView, but I don't want to use it for some reasons. As I understand, I need to resize the parent layout to the width of N*(width of screen), N is number of pages. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use an horizontal scrollView  and set your layout width by pixel like this

```
android:layout_width="2500px"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="2500dp"
```

And then add your layout to the scrollView.